# How to use useStore, useSelector, useDispatch hook?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

New hooks have been released with Redux version 7.1.0. I don't understand how to use these hooks in practice. Can someone give an example of how to use these hooks?

Comment: What about oficial documentation? https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks That seems nice. :) On first look for most cases u will only need useSelector as a replace for mapStateToProps and useDispatch for replace mapDispatchToProps.

Comment: @PavelKratochvil How do I understand He wants to see examples of how to use them?For me,official documentation there is no normal example.

Comment: So the next question which comes to my mind is: What is "normal" example? I can see example which show what is that hook doing and how to use it. What is wrong with that.?

Comment: If you feel the docs are insufficient, please file an issue.

Comment: @PavelKratochvil A good example is an example in practice.First, there is an explanation followed by practical use. [Watch it](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_let.asp)

Comment: @Brigita-Wasi This conversation seems a bit offtopic. So we can agree to disagree. Or if you want to continue in this conversation don't hesitate to contact me. I can argue my point of view.

Comment: @markerikson It will be difficult for beginners to understand redux hooks. I would add practical examples.

Comment: @Brigita-Wasi I'm from these newbies, you said everything correctly

Answer (score 3):

Please see [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-hooks-rvxud).

- `useSelector` is like `mapStateToProps`, you select properties from store and component is updated when store is changed
- `useDispatch` is just returning `dispatch`. It like calling `connect()` with empty second argument.
- `useStore` is used to retrieve `store`. But such store access can only be used for store manipulation, like reducer replacement. When store is changed, component which access store this way is not updated.

  Click Check2 button in example above and check2 is not checged untill you click 'update me' button

Comment: and why here need toString()?without this in any way.?when I removed toString(), it turned out that check1 is not visible.[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-hooks-hpbut)

Comment: `toString()` is required to show value of `check1` and `check2` as they are boolean. It is only for rendering

Comment: on your examples, change this part of the code ` Counter: {counter.toString()}`.

Comment: @Fyodor I agree with Tigran the Great. Why did you write so ` Counter: {counter.toString()}`,could just ` Counter: {counter}`.

Comment: Yes, sure. `toString()` is not needed with `counter`. Removed it.