# React JS and Redux: useSelector() vs useStore()

Tags: reactjs, redux

I would like to know what is the difference between useSelector and UseStore. Are there any advantages on using one instead of the other? Thanks.

**useSelector**

```
  const { pages } = useSelector((state: RootState) => {
    return {
      pages: state.pages
    };
  });
  console.log(pages);
```

**useStore**

```
  const pageArrayTwo = useStore();
  const pageArray = pageArrayTwo.getState().pages;
  console.log(pageArray);
```

**Same Output On Both Cases**

```
[{…}]
0: {id: 1, title: "Use Redux", content: "Welcome"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Here's the best explication I've found https://stackoverflow.com/a/57202109/11090321

Answer (score 20, accepted):

UseSelector, the main advantage here is that it does a shallow comparison of the previous selector result, thus potentially not re-rendering if the result would be the same.

> When an action is dispatched, `useSelector()` will do a reference
>   comparison of the previous selector result value and the current
>   result value. If they are different, the component will be forced to
>   re-render. If they are the same, the component will not re-render.

`useStore` just gets you access to the store object, do any component logic based on accessing the store's state won't benefit from this check. In fact, redux even recommends *against* using it for this purpose.

> **This hook should probably not be used frequently. Prefer `useSelector()`
>   as your primary choice.** However, this may be useful for less common
>   scenarios that do require access to the store, such as replacing
>   reducers.

Comment: I realize the docs advise against using `useStore`, however what about the case for accessing state within a callback? If the state is not used in UI and only needed lazily (ie only inside a callback/press handler), this seems like a decent way to prevent unneeded rerenders.

Comment: @sbearben What sort of access to state are you needing in a callback? `useStore` wouldn't be a valid React hook call in a callback. Instead you'd access state via the store's [getState](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getstate) method.

Comment: Exactly that, we'd use `getState` to access state within the callback. Apologies for not making it clear in my question.

Comment: @sbearben I see, is there still a question here then?

Answer (score 4):

**useSelector:** This is just a simple function, which takes in a function that takes the state as an argument and returns a value. Used to get a single value from state. Can act as a replacement for mapStateToProps.

**useDispatch:** returns a reference to the dispatch object. It can act as a replacement for mapDispatchToProps.

**useStore:** returns an instance of the store. Generally not recommended, because the component which uses this will not get updated. In such case use have to use react hooks like useEffect o explicitly update the component.

Please the [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-hooks-rvxud) here which is posted on other stack instance [other stackoverflow instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57197859/how-to-use-usestore-useselector-usedispatch-hook/57202109)